# use qml file for near similar content

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

i want to use my `ListView` of my qml in  2  Views of `QDeclarationView`
My Problem is, that the Deligate of one `ListView` must have one element more.

The Deligate is in a specific file (out of the `ListView` File)

Is there a method to make this element invisible for the second list view?

Greetings

Comment: What version of QML are you using? QML2 or 1?

Comment: QML2. I found out, that i can use  `setContextProperty("propertyname", "value");` for this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a intensive research, i found the 
`setContextProperty()`-Command.

```
QDeclarativeView *view= ui->content;
QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view->rootContext();
view->setSource( QUrl( "qrc:/...." ));
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("propertyName", "true");
```

with this i can catch the value for `propertyName` in qml like:

```
          Text {
              id: label 
              ...
              visible: propertyName;
           }
```

You also can set QObjects as content. 
Greetings